# Replace Text if found in the children of Element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following HTML being rendered on the page:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="100" nowrap="nowrap" class="ms-gb">
        <a href="javascript:" onclick="javascript:ExpCollGroup('0-1_', 'img_0-1_',event, false);return false;">
            <span class="commentcollapse-iconouter">
                <img class="commentcollapse-icon" src="Some Image" alt="collapse" id="img_0-1_" data-themekey="#">
            </span>
            iPad_Category
        </a>
         : AL Mobile 
        <span style="font-weight: lighter; display: inline-block;">(7)
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

[image]

Now my question is: What if I want to remove a keyword `iPad_Category` with the help of jQuery, what could it be? Additionally, how can I replace such text with the new one? For example,`: AL-Mobile`  should be replaced by `AL Mobile`, What's the best possible way to implement this with jQuery or JavaScript?

**Edit:**
I cannot remove `span` tag from the element as it has necessary event bound.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This isn't the duplicate question because what I want is to replace a string which no direct element. So I checked community for the same question and then only posted this question.

Comment: `var $td = $(".ms-gb"); $td.html($td.html().split("iPad_Category").join("").split(": AL").join("AL"))` or use replace.replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the HTML code of the target element then using `replace()` method you can replace and remove the parts you want, finally return the new HTML with replaced data and override the original one like :

```js
var new_structure = $("#my-div").html().replace(': AL Mobile', 'AL Mobile').replace('iPad_Category', '');

$("#my-div").html(new_structure);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="my-div">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="100" nowrap="nowrap" class="ms-gb">
      <a href="javascript:" onclick="javascript:ExpCollGroup('0-1_', 'img_0-1_',event, false);return false;">
        <span class="commentcollapse-iconouter">
                <img class="commentcollapse-icon" src="Some Image" alt="collapse" id="img_0-1_" data-themekey="#">
            </span> iPad_Category
      </a>
      : AL Mobile
      <span style="font-weight: lighter; display: inline-block;">(7)
        </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @pradip-r is this what you want ?

Comment: I have used `text()` before and assigned back but that removed my span html. Your answer is helpful and working. Appreciate it!!